# Android emulator on Fedora 26 (CentOS)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Изучаю мобильную разработку, использую операционную систему **Fedora 26/27**, обычно при разработке я использую **смартфон**, компилирую приложение напрямую в него, хотел попробовать запускать тесты из эмулятора, но толком нормальных эмуляторов на эту операционку не нашел, пробовал **Genymotion** и **Android Studio**, **Genymotion** ругался на неустановленный **VirtualBox** (хотя он был установлен), а **Android Studio** просто не вывозил мой компьютер :)
Хотел бы узнать на сколько вообще профитно использовать **Android emulators** и какие нормальные варианты есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал стандартный эмулятор в комплекте с android sdk. Только x86, который поддерживает аппаратную виртуализацию. Если у вас процессор Intel, то все будет хорошо на любой ОС по инструкции https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html
Если AMD, то с ускорением будет работать только на Linux.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)

Comment: Можно ли с вами пообщаться в соц сети или же мессенджере?

Comment: Можно. Написал на почту.